# Switching between windows with scroll wheel on Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock, mouse-scroll

I would like to switch between windows using the scroll wheel of the mouse over each app icon in Ubuntu dock, as we could do in Unity, but apparently this doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.10.

Is there a way to enable it?

[image]

---

Related: [How do I enable 'minimize on click' on Ubuntu dock in 17.10 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960074/480481)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

Comment: Yes, it still works after reboot.

Comment: Why there is no GUI support! not even by tweaks tool.

Comment: UPDATE: Installed the origin gnome dash-to-dock extension, now I can edit the settings. Are they (gnome dash-to-dock and ubuntu dock) just sharing the settings or they're basically the same!

Comment: @AmirKarimi Ubuntu Dock is a fork of dash-to-dock extension.

Comment: @pomsky Do you have any idea why there is no settings button available for Ubuntu Dock in tweak like what is there for dash-to-dock?

Comment: It works also in Ubuntu 18.04. But in the GUI `Editor dconf` the `cycle-windows` option is'nt listed and isn't showd as current option.

Comment: Ahhh Finally! Thanks, been working like a savage for weeks! lol

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) and worked.

Comment: Tested it on Ubuntu 20.04 and works like a charm.

Comment: It seems working for a switch from one app to another. However a more useful and logical feature seems to be switching among multiple windows of that same app above which the mouse is scrolling, isn't it?

Comment: @funicorn Sounds like there's something wrong in your setup. The question and the answer are completely about switching between windows of the same application, there's nothing regarding switching applications.

Comment: I ran the command in my Ubuntu 18.04 and didn't get any error. However, it's not working! Could you please let me know any possible fixes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Milan Try the detailed Solution 1 part from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966522/480481) posted to a similar question.

Comment: @pomsky apologies for the late reply. But for that Solution 1, I have to install ***Dash to Dock***, right? Is there any other way to achieve this switching without installing *Dash to Dock*?

Comment: @pomsky thanks again for your reply. Yup for `get` method, it's showing that `scroll-action` has already been set to `'cycle-windows'`. This had not been working previously. However, I don't know what happened... after installing ***Dash to Dock***, I disabled it using **Tweak Tools** app, and now I can scroll!! Thanks again for your time and prompt replies :)

Comment: Still works on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` in 2022

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.04 :)

Comment: I did it on Ubuntu 22 but the whole dock scrolls simultaneously with open windows. Can I disable simultaneous dock scrolling somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For those who get the message (pop_os 20.04):

```
No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock”
```

The solution is a longer:

```
gsettings --schemadir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/schemas/ set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

**Explanations**:

I've manually installed my dash-to-dock directly in the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, which is where the `schemas` directory is located. It has to be specified explicitly.

Usage of gsettings:

```
gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE
```

Set the value of KEY to VALUE with Arguments:

```
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set
```

To list the current KEYs and their VALUEs:

```
gsettings --schemadir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/schemas/ list-recursively org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock
```

[Source](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/871#issuecomment-454819437) of inspiration

Comment: You'll get the `No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock”` in pop_os, but it's highly unlikely in a standard Ubuntu 20.04 installation. Ubuntu comes with the 'Ubuntu Dock' extension (fork of dash-to-dock) by default, hence the schema is present. On the other hand pop_os doesn't come with any such extension. In this aspect pop_os and Ubuntu are very much not the same.

Comment: You are correct, the schema was only for pop_os, edited to reflect your remark. And I had installed the extension manually.