# App key {Super+number} with num pad

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, ubuntu-dock

The app shortcut key (alt + number) works fine with the numbers above the main keyboard keys but not with the num pad keys in Ubuntu 17.10 anymore (it worked fine on Ubuntu 17.04).
How could we fix that?

EDIT: Moreover, the shortcut doesn't open one of the windows of the application as it used to do (top window). It shows all windows instead... This is a bit annoying too :/

Comment: Apparently it was an intentional change made by "Dash to Dock" developers (Ubuntu Dock in Artful is a fork of Dash to Dock). "*The only other significant change in this update is a change to shortcuts behaviour for the Super + num shortcut used to launch apps (Unity style). This shortcut now only associates with the keyboard’s top row number keys and not (where available) those of a numeric keyboard. This change avoids conflicts with other keyboard shortcuts.*" (from [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/dash-dock-61-unity-style-background))

Comment: Oh... What a shame. I tried Unity and the old keyboard shortcuts do work but some other things are broken (sound volume keys for example).
Would there be a way to use unity shortcuts for {super + num} functionality but not for other things?

Comment: I found this gnome extension, which does just that: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a gnome extension that adds these Super+NUM hotkeys:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/

And for the problem of preview instead of cycling through windows of an application, you can set an option to cycle instead of preview like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

For more information: https://robertianhawdon.me.uk/2017/11/02/quick-tip-changing-ubuntu-17-10s-dock-behaviour/

If the setting "click-action" is not available, you can add the gnome extension for dash-to-dock here: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/ (and uninstall it later)

Comment: You may also activate the option to [switch between windows with the mouse wheel/touchpad scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-dock).