# Some applications (Chromimum, Firefox) not showing Application Menu in 18.04 + Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, chromium, 18.04, mozilla

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 with a basic Gnome 3 configuration, I noticed that some applications such as Chromium and Firefox Mozilla do not show the application menu. As such, it makes it difficult to switch between windows.

As a developer, I almost always have a window with a bunch of tabs open. Then a second icognito window for testing purposes. Switching between the two is hard without the menu.

On Mac OS X, "Chrome" has File, Edit, View, History, Bookmarks, People, Window and Help on the main toolbar of the application.

Thanks in advance.

[Chromium with no menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ2IM.png)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Could you explain a bit more what is missing (maybe with a screenshot)?

Comment: Added a screenshot. Not much to see though. I updated the description of the problem above. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: In Firefox you should get the menu bar by pressing alt key. Also you can right on an empty space in tab-bar and check "Menu Bar" option to show it permanently. What I'm not getting is how the menu bar is supposed to help you switch between windows easily. alt+tab is a better option IMO. Also you can try some creative alternatives like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-dock