# How can I turn off click to minimize only for applications that have multiple windows opened?

Tags: window, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, minimize

I enabled click to minimize but now it's hard to get to the windows that I have opened. I have to right click, select all windows and then choose the one I want to switch to.

How can I make it behave as it does on Microsoft Windows? It should only minimize when there's a single window open and show the windows when there are multiple open.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with the GNOME desktop.

Comment: @pomsky Yes, on the dock. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Okay, I added some more relevant tags. It's not answer, but try setting [switch-on-scoll-wheel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock) along with the *minimize-on-click* option. You may find it useful for switching between windows of the same application.

Comment: @pomsky That works but I'm looking for a Windows-like behavior. I don't see it in the options for click-action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command to get something close to what you're after

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-overview'
```

Now if you have only one window of an application open, clicking its icon in Ubuntu dock would switch between minimised and restored states. But if you have multiple windows of the application open, then clicking on the icon would open "*Activities*" overview from where you would be able to select you preferred window.