# How to change the behavior of clicking on grouped apps in launcher

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

On one of my computers, clicking on an Icon on the launcher that has  multiple application grouped will toggle between opening all the Windows in the group, or minimzing all the windows in the group.

On all the other computers, when there is more than one item on the icon, it will bring up the list and allow the user scroll through the icon list and click on just one application.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior to the default, whereas it will bring up the list if there is more than one icon in the group, and toggle restore/minimize when there is only one in the group?

You can see this list with a sequence of keystrokes:

- right click the icon
- click all windows
- click the application instance from the list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`gsettings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gsettings.1.html) to achieve your goal

If you run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

you should see different outputs for two different cases you mentioned, for example in the first scenario it should give `minimize` whereas in the second case it should be `previews`.

To set the preferred option as per the output of the command above, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'YOUR-PREFERRED-OPTION'
```

In particular, to achieve your goal, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Comment: Thanks.  The command you gave for shoing the different cases only shows the one case that is currently in effect.  It showed `minimize`.  I went to one of the other computers and found the their setting which is `previews`.  It works like a charm.  You might consider adding the clarity to the answer for others having the same problem, but one computer... or show a command that will actually list the choices.

Comment: Another available action I find very useful is 'cycle-windows'. Instead of opening previews if there is more than one window open, it cycles through them. This is specially useful when combined with `SUPER+#` shortcuts so that you can directly access specific applications and cycle through all their windows.

Comment: @kepler I find setting the ['cycle-windows' option to mouse-scroll](https://askubuntu.com/q/966887/480481) useful, especially when I'm using a mouse with scroll-wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @pomsky.

Answer (score 5):

You can user dconf editor GUI tool to update these changes easily

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

[image]