# Click on sidebar opens last opened application

Tags: 20.04

My issue since updating to 20.04 is that when clicking on a sidebar (dock) application with more than 1 instance, it opens the last active window. The second click on the icon opens the list of instances.

This may have changed in 19.x, I upgraded recently from 18.

Previously it showed the options first. I could then select which instance I wanted to use.

Is this configurable?

[image: Example of side bar]

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Thanks to this answer:
[How to change the behavior of clicking on grouped apps in launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099752/how-to-change-the-behavior-of-clicking-on-grouped-apps-in-launcher)