# Does Ubuntu have the option to ctrl+click an icon in the dash to cycle between instances of that program?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

On Windows, a very useful feature for multitasking is that you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click an icon on the toolbar to cycle between instances of that program, so if I have three instances of chrome open I can cycle between them without having to find one and then use a keyboard shortcut or click it and try to pick the correct one from the icons.

Put simply I want to know if this is something I can enable on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. When you left click all windows disappear except chrome ones. All screens darken except chrome windows appear brighter. You can then move pointer to select one. When you right click a drop down list appears where you can select which chrome window you want. Mind you I did this in 16.04 and Firefox which has three most windows open. This under Unity which you indicate you are using.

Comment: 16.04 must be different then, because none of what you just said happens, when I left click the icon a set of previews come up that are mostly useless to tell what I want because most websites I use look the same, and right clicking an icon brings up a context menu with things like "remove from favourites"

Comment: Related: [Switching between windows with scroll wheel on Ubuntu Dock](https://askubuntu.com/q/966887/480481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may not be able to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click to do what you want, you can make it such that clicking successively on the icon cycles through open instances. If your dash currently does not currently behave like that, then you can set it that way with the command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'`

While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click will launch or switch to an application, it will not do extra actions (e.g., it will not cycle). To my knowledge, you cannot further customize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click behaviour.

However, you can further customize <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click behaviour, and in addition middle-click and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + middleclick.

Use the `gsettings range` command to query the possible values of the different keys controlling click behavour, i.e., `click-action`, `shift-click-action`, `middle-click-action` and `shift-middle-click-action`, for example:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Then use a `gsettings set` command (see first command for an example) as above to set one of the available values. Use a `gsettings reset` command to reset the value to the default value of Ubuntu, for example

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```