# Ubuntu Dock disappearing when horizontal-scrolling on it

Tags: gnome, scrolling, dock

On Ubuntu 18.04, the Dock (sidebar ?) keeps disappearing when I do a horizontal scroll on it.

Thanks to [this blog](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-Dock-Disappear/) I can make it reappear by restarting the gnome shell, but I think this is still a bug that needs to be mentioned.

Is anyone able to reproduce this bug ? I can't find any other mention of this. What should I do to report it ?

(An easy fix would be : stop horizontal-scrolling on the Dock ! Yes but I use normal scrolling on the Dock to switch between windows, and using a gamepad as a mouse, scrolling on the joystick often does a little bit of horizontal scrolling as well.)

Comment: Silly question, do you have the same issue when the dock is at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Same thing on the bottom : Normal scrolling switches windows (thanks to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock)), but horizontal scrooling makes it disappear.
Changing the dock position between _left_ and _bottom_ also makes it reappear.

Comment: That is very strange. Do you have hide dock enabled in settings?

Comment: @Robby1212 nope

Comment: @PhanPhan did you eventually solve it? I had the same bug in Ubuntu 19.10 and now I upgraded to 20.04 and it's even worse (pls see my post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231083/bug-20-04-system-irresponsive-after-horizontal-scrolling-on-dock)

Comment: I just found out that if I disable IMWheel the issue is gone. Not able to set mouse scroll speed anymore, though.