# How to apply Ubuntu 14.04's dock on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 14.04, 20.04, application-development, dock

there!
Hope everyone is doing fine.
I've recently upgraded my laptop, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I do miss the wonderful dock the former does have. I mean, scrolling on the dock I could easily switch amongst windows (applications, files, etc), no additional clicks.

Would anyone know how to have it on Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're talking about Ubuntu 14.04's default desktop (Unity), it can still be used on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, however the default is now GNOME (it became default in the 17.10 release, with 17.04 the last with Unity). It's not just a dock, but a different desktop (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-unity-desktop) but is that what you mean? or something else?

Comment: Also, you can use this unofficial derivative of ubuntu, which has been tailored for Unity desktop. https://ubuntuunity.org/

Comment: Hi! I've followed this article https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2020/05/ubuntu-unity-focal-fossa.html, but the magnifying glass (see screenshot) doesn't appear in the top, do you know how I can have it?
Screenshot https://snipboard.io/hfXnTY.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since quite a few versions, Ubuntu moved from its own Unity desktop to the Gnome Shell desktop. The Ubuntu Dock in current session works quite the same as that in Unity.

- You can [change the behaviour of the Dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock) so that scrolling the mouse over an app's icon switches windows. To do this, use either `dconf-editor` (not installed by default), or use the following command:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'`
- You can continue to use the Unity shell, which is still available. Install `unity-session`. Then log out, and before logging in, use the cog wheel to select the Unity session.