# Ubuntu 17.10, open last used window from group, when clicked in Dock

Tags: gnome, launcher, 17.10, dock, ubuntu-dock

Is there a way to have the same behavior from Unity, where if you had multiple windows from the same application open, when you click on the icon in the Dock (Launcher in Unity), it will open the last used window.

The new GNOME on Ubuntu 17.10 repeatedly gives you a popup to choose which window you want? Is there a way to revert to the Unity behavior?

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: @pomsky thanks, but I would go with the 'cycle-windows' value, as minimize does not let you see the other windows

Comment: You can do that, or maybe use `'cycle-window'` [with mouse-wheel/touchpad scroll](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-dock).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the behavior of the click action can be changed with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

`cycle-windows` is the closest behavior to unity.

You can list other values with:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: or simply [check the XML](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/blob/master/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.gschema.xml)

Comment: You can also install the dconf editor (`sudo apt-get install -y dconf-editor`) and make those modifications using a GUI interface, if you prefer. I recommend installing that, so you can visually go over a myriad of options there, which may not even know existed. The path to change this feature on dconf-editor (Ubuntu 18) would be: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock.click-action`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for even more Unity-like behaviour, ie open last window ***on a particular monitor***, just set the following

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true
```

If you have multiple monitors, this will cause a window to open on the monitor which you click the dock icon on.