# How to show all open windows from sample app

Tags: gnome, 17.10, ubuntu-dock

I have multiple instances of an app open, e.g. of Terminal. Indicated by the orange dots next to the icon.

[image]

Can I configure a shortcut to restore/ show all of those windows with a single click/ command, e.g. double click on the launcher?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-dock

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but a nice workaround/ alternative.

Comment: If you enable "minimise on click" following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-17-10), clicking an application icon in the dock would switch between minimising and restoring all the associated application windows.

Comment: That is kind of what I was looking for. In combination with the mouse wheel there is all needed flexibility now, thanks!