# How do I turn off minimize-on-click option for Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, gsettings, minimize

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and used this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

to turn on minimize on dock with single click on icon. How to revert back and turn off this feature?

Because it's irritating for browser if multiple window open. How to exclude browsers from this settings and/or how to revert back system wide?

Comment: You could have find out the answer by looking at the *man page* by running `man gsettings` in a terminal or looking at the man page at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gsettings.1.html

Comment: You may try activating the option to [switch between windows with mouse-scroll](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-dock) along with click to minimise. They work really well together imo.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can revert to the default option by running

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Also try running

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

then you'll get all possible values that can be set. See if you find another option preferable.

Comment: Pretty self explained command. Thank you, it did work.

Comment: Also you can use `get` to see current value: `gsettings get org.gnome...`

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-overview'
```

This does exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are looking for a Windows-like "click-action", use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-previews'
```

Comment: Good answer. This is applicable to newer versions of Ubuntu Dock, was not available in older versions.