# Is combinining more than one gsettings options for click-action on Ubuntu dock possible?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gsettings

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I would like to use two different settings for click-action on the Ubuntu dock.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

When using this two commands only the last one is working. These commands are overwriting each other.

Is there a way to have both active at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Update:** On newer versions of Ubuntu dock, this feature can be turned on by simply running the following command in Terminal:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-previews'
> ```

---

**Original answer:**

No, it's not possible (yet). Dash to Dock developers did implement a `'minimize-or-previews'` action in [version 63](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/changelog.html#v63), but this version is not available in the [official site](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) yet and Ubuntu dock being a fork of Dash to Dock also doesn't support the action yet.

But you can set one action to mouse click and another to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+mouse-click as an alternative. For example, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

to set `'minimize'` action to mouse-click. Then run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-click-action 'previews'
```

to set `'previews'` action to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+mouse-click.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu dock has been updated now, so at least for me, `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-previews'` did work.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Thanks for the pointer, I forgot about this answer. I have already updated my answer posted to the [canonical question](https://askubuntu.com/q/960074/480481), now I have updated this one too.

Comment: Wow it's 3 years and 8 months after i posted my question and see your updated answer. It finally works! Thx!! :D