# "gnome-tweak-tool: command not found" after installation

Tags: apt, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

Suspecting that it's not installed I tried again:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.28.1-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  app-install-data apt-xapian-index couchdb-common libnih-dbus1
  libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test
  libqtassistantclient4 python-apt python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-attr python-automat python-blinker
  python-click python-colorama python-constantly python-cups python-debian
  python-defer python-dirspec python-httplib2 python-hyperlink
  python-incremental python-jwt python-oauthlib python-pam
  python-piston-mini-client python-pycurl python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus
  python-serial python-twisted-bin python-xapian python-xdg
  python-zope.interface python3-piston-mini-client python3-xapian
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I also tried installing my computer with no difference. I still get:

```
gnome-tweak-tool: command not found
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

How do I actually start `gnome-tweak-tool`?

Comment: @pomsky gnome-tweak-tool: command not found

Comment: What happens if you run `gnome-tweaks` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 aka Bionic Beaver the `gnome-tweak-tool` is a *transitional* package which is used to pull in a different package, in your case `gnome-tweaks` to make upgrades more smooth when a package name had to be renamed. For whatever reasons...

You can see this information when using `apt-cache show gnome-tweak-tool`. The `Depends:` line is the package that is pulled in.

So to run it, just enter `gnome-tweaks` or use `dpkg -L gnome-tweaks` to list the files that are shipped with that package.

Comment: Thanks! All I wanted to do was enable click to minimize on the dock. Couldn't find that option. I would appreciate your help if you know where it is...

Comment: @Alex You won't find any option like that in Tweaks. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-18-04) for an answer.

Comment: @pomsky `gsettings` command did the job for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The `gnome-tweak-tools` package provides the binary, `gnome-tweaks`.  If  you check out the package's details, either in the CLI or through [Ubuntu Packages Website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-tweak-tool) you can see this, where it shows the package provides `gnome-tweaks`.

You should be able to run `gnome-tweaks`, and the command will be found.

Using the package information, but also installing `bash-completion`, and using your <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the terminal, will help you figure these things out a bit faster.  Here, you could have typed `gnome-TABTAB`, and gotten a list of available commands, showing `gnome-tweaks`.