# How to toggle window visibility with Ubuntu 18.04 dock?

Tags: gnome-panel, dock, ubuntu-dock

In Windows, when you have a window on the foreground and you click on its taskbar button, it becomes minimized.

Is there a setting which allows same behavior with Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome environment) dock?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable 'minimize on click' on Ubuntu dock in Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10-and-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

if not installed install dconf editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

open it, use the search icon on the top bar and search for `dock`, open the first result (it should be `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`), now adjust the value for click-action to minimize.