# GNOME minimizing/restoring all windows of a specific application

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

In GNOME desktop, how can I minimize/restore all windows *of a specific application*?

I know the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> hides all normal windows and then restores them, but I'm looking for its equivalent that works only for windows of a given application (for example, the application running in the current window).

Comment: I belatedly recognized there is a duplicate question, with better answers: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107496/how-to-quickly-minimize-all-windows-for-a-single-application?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with rather a hacky, non-universal solution using `wmctrl` and `xdotool`. A custom keyboard shortcut registered with the command

```
/bin/bash -c "for wid in $(wmctrl -l -p | grep $(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid) | awk '{print $1}') ; do xdotool windowactivate $wid > /dev/null 2>&1 ; done"
```

activates specific windows that have the same PID as the current one's, and works as desired with applications like GNOME Terminal, Nautilus, Firefox, and others. The minimization shortcut can be added with the `windowminimize` option replacing `windowactivate`. I tested the shortcuts in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME version 3.28.4.

Since the command discriminates windows by their PIDs, this solution does not work when windows of the same application have different PIDs.