# Can I make Ubuntu 18.04 switch between multiple windows of the program by just clicking the icon?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock

I just want a Windows 7 behavior where clinking the icon cycles through all the windows. I know about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Tilde) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> clicking the icon is just more intuitive.

Comment: If you have a mouse with scroll-wheel, I find [switching between windows with scroll wheel](https://askubuntu.com/q/966887/480481) along with '[minimise on click](https://askubuntu.com/q/960074/480481)' a better alternative.

Comment: Not an answer as you tagged gnome-shell, but KDE Plasma works a lot more like Windows 7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

Comment: That works... sadly no more Click to Minimize. It would be nice if you could Minimize when there is one window open and Cycle-windows when there are 2 or more. Oh well... thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean **Enabling Click to Minimize** (minimize the window when clicking on the icon) as shown in the gif photo:

[image]

It is simple, you can do that by running the following command in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

If you do not like ‘click to minimize’ behavior, you can set it back to default using the command below:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: No I meant if I had two office files open and I clicked the icon so it cycles between them (it's a windows7 behavior). I have Click to Minimize enabled.

Comment: Well then, you will not be able to minimize on click the icons :/

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is tagged ubuntu-dock* but if you are using the Dash to Panel extension you can find a similar setting in Tweaks > Extensions > Dash to panel > Behaviour > Click Action > Set to Cycle through windows.

* the title is broad and Google may pick this up as a search

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor by

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Goto **/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock** and change **click-action** to **cycle-windows**