# How can I minimize an application from the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock, minimize

If I click a minimized application from the dock it will show the window, but a second click does nothing. Also, the right click menu has no option to minimize. I have seen answers involving modifying the dock behavior with extensions like dash-to-dock, but is there a way to minimize from the dock without modifying it or using extensions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable 'minimize on click' on Ubuntu dock in 17.10 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-dock-in-17-10-and-later) You don't need to install dash-to-dock, the Ubuntu Dock itself is a fork of dash-to-dock and hence supports almost all of dash-to-dock's configuration options. You just need to run a single command; see the 'Solution 2' of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966522/480481).

Answer (score 2):

Shift+Middle-Click is the default way to do this.

Comment: Hey rynn1x! Do accept your answer. https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer